# Dir command is not printing the files and folder size

Tags: python

```
    date_string = r'C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.16\g\after\said\%s' % (now.strftime('%Y.%b\%d'))
   if os.path.dirname('C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.16\g\after\said\%s' % (now.strftime('%Y.%b\%d'))):
      print "File exist"
      #sizefile = "".join("cd", date_string)
      #print sizefile
      sathya = os.system('dir /s ' +date_string)
      print(sathya)
else:
      print "no"
```

Output is :

```
File exist
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is F497-220A
File Not Found
1

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>
```

Please help.

I fixed this by using sub process, Find the below code;

```
date_string = r''C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.16\g\after\said\%s' % (now.strftime('%Y.%b\%d'))
    cmd = "dir /s"+" "+date_string+ ">> gad"
    subprocess.call(cmd , shell=True)
```

Please use subprocess instead of os.system().

Comment: try to pass date_string into os.path.dirname:
if os.path.dirname(date_string)

Comment: And BTW, you question is related to windows command line, not for python.

Comment: Vadym, for the same command  i m getting output 48 File(s)        411,227 bytes

Comment: GNK, did you try os.path.dirname(date_string) ?

Comment: Yes I tried. That will will work my concern is about sathya = os.system('dir /s ' +date_string) this line

Comment: I suppose that the problem could be in encoding. Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068812/problem-using-os-system-with-sed-command

Comment: Try to use subprocess

Comment: Thanks for your time Vadym. will try subprocess a

Comment: I fixed the issue by using subprocess. date_string = r''C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.16\g\after\said\%s' % (now.strftime('%Y.%b\%d'))
cmd = "dir /s"+" "+date_string+ ">> gad"
subprocess.call(cmd , shell=True)

Comment: Could you please answer on your question and write your solution?

Comment: @RedEyed, I don't have privileges to answer.