# Run a GhostScript command in Python from windows

Tags: python, command-line, ghostscript

I have a GhostScript command (windows command prompt) that I would like to execute from Python.
I can successfully run :

```
os.system(gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=tiff24nc -r300 -o fullfilename.tiff fullfilename)
```

But I get an error with :

```
os.system(gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=tiff24nc -r300 -o fullfilename.tiff -g235x49 -c "<</Install {-478 -743 translate}>> setpagedevice" -f fullfilename)
```

While this command works fine in command prompt.
I narrowed it down to this being the issue :

```
-c "<</Install {-478 -743 translate}>> setpagedevice"
```

It seems like there are characters that are interpreted by python instead of GhostScript. 
If I print the command, it return 1. So there is an error.
Can't figure out how to strictly pass the whole command to the windows command prompt.
Thanks
Happouh

Answer (score 0):

I thought I reviewed all possible posts, but here was the answer : [Problem using os.system() with sed command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068812/problem-using-os-system-with-sed-command).
Use: import subprocess.
Then call your command : subprocess.call(command)